# Java Regex quickie

Tags: java, regex

I'm feeling silly that I cannot figure this out, but it's really starting to piss me off.

I'm simply trying to ensure the string contains only digits using `string.match(regex)`. If it contains any non-numeric characters, hard code it to 9999999.

Here's my code. I'm essentially checking to see if the results I pull from the `ResultSet` moduleResults contains no non-numeric characters before use it to `setEndPointID` which accepts a long as its parameter. The `trim()` is in there because there are often leading spaces in `id_amr_module` and I don't want those to throw off the regex match. I've also tried the regex [0-9]* with no success.

```
String strEndPointID = moduleResults.getString("id_amr_module");
strEndPointID.trim();
if(strEndPointID.matches("\\d*")){
  msiRF.setEndpointID(moduleResults.getLong("id_amr_module"));
}
else{
  long lngEndPointID = 99999999;
  msiRF.setEndpointID(lngEndPointID);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You need [start and end anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to make sure the *entire* string is numeric.</s> You also need to use `+` instead of `*` so that the regexp matches at least 1 digit (`^\\d*$` would match the empty string). Fully refactored:

```
long endPointID = 99999999;
String strEndPointID = moduleResults.getString("id_amr_module").trim();
if(strEndPointID.matches("^\\d+$")){
    endPointID = Long.parseLong(strEndPointID);
}
msiRF.setEndpointID(endPointID);
```

Comment: String.matches() doesn't need anchors.

Comment: You're right. Goes to show how often I use `String#matches()`. I guess the only thing the OP was missing was `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: +1 for correcting the OP's use of `trim()`, too.  @TyC, the way you used it had no effect because you didn't assign the result of the `trim()` to the variable: `strEndPointID = strEndPointID.trim();`

Comment: Thank you @AlanMoore. It took me only a minute to realize why it  STILL wasn't working (due to not assigning the trim()).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your regular expression searches for any number of digits. What you are looking for is something like this: `^\d+$`

- `^` means the start of the string
- `\d+` means at least one digit
- `$` means the end of the string

Comment: actually... The start and end anchors shouldn't be necessary, at least if someone believes what is written on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

Comment: Mhm. I never noticed that. That's definitely odd. Still...it doesn't really solve the question then and still the author accepted an answer very similar to mine. ;)

Comment: The fix was replacing "*" with "+", which you both got right.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex should be:

```
"^\\d*$"
```

`^` - start from beginning 
`\\d*` - match as many digits as you find
`$` - until reaching the end of string

Comment: -1 Incorrect - String.matches() doesn't need anchors. This doesn't address the problem in any way.